# write location / gps coordinates to a file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, location, core-location

Well, I know it may sounds basic, but I have literally been looking everywhere and could not find a straight answer to that. I am trying to save location coordinates to a file every time I get an update - sounds simple.... I have two problems: one is with the data type (writeToFile seems to save only NSData) and the other one is with appending to the end of the file. I tried to use NSKeyedArchiver but it wrote a bunch of garbage and I could not find how to append to the end of file with it.

Here is my code - if you could help I would greatly appreciate that. Thanks!

```
....

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *numLat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.latitude];
NSNumber *numLong = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.longitude];


[array addObject:numLat];    
[array addObject:numLong];    

NSFileHandle *file;
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: @"./location.txt"];

if (file == nil)
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file");


[file seekToEndOfFile];

[file writeData: array]; //BTW - this line doesn't work if I replace array with numLat which is an NSNumber - unlike what many people have said in various discussions here
```

OR - for the saving to file portion (last two lines):

```
NSString *path = @"./location.txt";
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:array toFile:path];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the path to the Documents (this is where your app saves data)
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
[array writeToFile:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"location"] atomically:YES];
```

To load the data back into the array, use

```
NSArray *searchPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsPath = [searchPaths objectAtIndex: 0];
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"location"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but how can I append to end of file with that? I tired to use it and write twice, then when I read I only get the last write.

Comment: @TommyG when you use the writeToFile method on the array, it will write the entire array out, overwriting anything that was there before.  So if you are creating a new array (rather than loading it from the file) then writing it out again will only write the new data you added to the array since the initialization of the array.  To append, you will need to load the data back into the array, then add your new data to the array and then write the array out again.  Depending on the amount of data you are writing, you may get speed/memory concerns.

Comment: So whats the best practice for that? What do people do when needing to append to end of file?

Comment: It depends on the volumes of data.  If you are dealing with small amounts and you need to re-use the previous data, just load and save using that.  If you are looking at LOTS of data, then think about using core data to a database and then writing that data to a file when it is required.

Comment: basically i want to save user location and then send it to the server once a day (for example). so every time i get a location, i need to save it locally - that can mean once a second even...so should I load and save every second? all I want is to save a series of location and time stamps. i have to append it every single new sample, right? or at least every time the app is terminated (it can run in the background though), but still, most likely this will happen a few times within a period of a day (meaning, until i upload it to a server/db)